# YUP - Required field validation not working when there are optional or not required fields in the same schema

Tags: javascript, yup

I am using yup to validate a simple form where almost all fields are not required, only name is required. So I've created the following schema (sample version):

```
const contatoCadastroSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().min(3, 'Mínimo de 3 letras').required('Nome é obrigatório'),
    last_name: yup.string().min(3, 'Mínimo de 3 letras').notRequired(),
    document: yup.string().test('cpf-validação', 'O CPF deve ser válido', (value) => validarCPF(value)).notRequired()
});
```

The validation for "name" only works if I send one of the other two fields. If I send it alone it does not work.
I also realized that if I remove the other validations or make them required, the name validation works. Also if I remove only the .test() validation for document it also works.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'when' method for conditional checking.

```
const contatoCadastroSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().min(3, 'Mínimo de 3 letras').required('Nome é obrigatório'),
  last_name: yup.string().min(3, 'Mínimo de 3 letras').notRequired(),
  document: yup.string().test('cpf-validação', 'O CPF deve ser válido', (value) => validarCPF(value)).notRequired(),
})

.when(['last_name', 'document'], (last_name, document, schema) => {
  // If either last_name or document is provided, make name required
  if (last_name || document) {
    return schema.required('Nome é obrigatório');
  }
});
```